# I am not getting any Message from Remote system in UDP Java Programming

Tags: java, udp

First program which runs on my computer

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;




public class NewUDP22   /*main class*/

{


    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception


    {  


      /*calling both threads ReceiveDataClass and SendDataClass*/



              ReceiveDataClass t=new ReceiveDataClass();


              SendDataClass obj=new SendDataClass();


              t.start();/*starting threads here*/


              obj.start();


    }   


}


class ReceiveDataClass extends Thread


{

    byte receiveData[]=new byte[10024];


    DatagramSocket ds;


    DatagramPacket dp;


 public void run()


     {


      try{ 


         while(true)


           {



        //byte receiveData[]=new byte[1024];


        ds=new DatagramSocket(50000);


        dp=new DatagramPacket(receiveData,receiveData.length);


        ds.receive(dp);


        String str=new String(dp.getData());


        System.out.println("person1:      "+str);


        ds.close();



            }
    }

   catch(Exception e){}
}


}


class SendDataClass extends Thread


  {


    public void run()


    {


        try


        {
             while(true)


              {


                byte sendData[]=new byte[100924];


                DatagramPacket dp;


            InetSocketAddress sd=new InetSocketAddress("192.168.8.101",40000);


                DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket();


                BufferedReader dis;


                dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


                String data=dis.readLine();


                System.out.println("me:    "+data);


                sendData=data.getBytes();


                dp=new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length,sd);


                ds.send(dp);


                ds.close();


            }

        }

      catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

Here is the second program which runs on different system

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;


public class NewUDP2   /*main class*/

{


    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception


    {  


      /*calling both threads ReceiveDataClass and SendDataClass*/



              ReceiveDataClass t=new ReceiveDataClass();



              SendDataClass obj=new SendDataClass();



              t.start();/*starting threads here*/



              obj.start();
    }   

}


class ReceiveDataClass extends Thread

{


    byte receiveData[]=new byte[10024];



    DatagramSocket ds;



    DatagramPacket dp;



 public void run()


     {


      try{ 


         while(true)


           {


        //byte receiveData[]=new byte[1024];



        ds=new DatagramSocket(40000);


        dp=new DatagramPacket(receiveData,receiveData.length);


        ds.receive(dp);


        String str=new String(dp.getData());


        System.out.println("person1:      "+str);


        ds.close();

       }

    }catch(Exception e){}

  }

}


class SendDataClass extends Thread


  {


    public void run()


    {


        try


        {


             while(true)


              {



                byte sendData[]=new byte[100924];


                DatagramPacket dp;


 InetSocketAddress  sd=new  InetSocketAddress("192.168.8.101",50000);


                DatagramSocket ds=new DatagramSocket();


                BufferedReader dis;


                dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


                String data=dis.readLine();


                System.out.println("me:    "+data);


                sendData=data.getBytes();


                dp=new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length,sd);


                ds.send(dp);


                ds.close();


            }



        }catch(IOException e){}


    }


}
```

When I run this both program on two different system then I can send the message on second system and He is also receiving the message. But when message is being sent by Remote System to my System then I am not able to get any message, even though message has sent by Remote System. I tried all ways which I could do. This is for a project in my university.

Here are the screen shot of both systems:

[This is first snap shot of my system  output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbfd5.png)

[This is second snap shot of remote system output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4udN.jpg)

Comment: Please remove the Android tag, this has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All coding are correct .just close windows firewall in your System as well as other antivirus also.because it does not allow to receive any type of UDP packets.